# Convert DataTable to LINQ: Unable to query multiple fields

Tags: c#, linq, datatable

Importing a spreadsheet I have filled a DataTable object with that data and returns expected results.

Attempting to put this into a format I can easily query to search for problem records I have done the following

```
public void Something(DataTable dt)
{
     var data = from row in dt.AsEnumerable()
                select row["Order"].ToString();
}
```

Works as expected giving me a list of orders.  However I cannot add other fields to this EnumerableRowCollection.  Attempting to add other fields as follows gives me an error

```
public void Something(DataTable dt)
{
     // row["Version"] throws an error on me
     var data = from row in dt.AsEnumerable()
                select row["Order"].ToString(), row["Version"].ToString();
}
```

Error: "A local variable named 'row' cannot be declared in this scope because it would give a different meaning to 'row' which is already used in a 'child' scope to donate something else"

I'm thinking I need to alias the column name but I'm having no luck.  What am I missing here?

Comment: It would really help if you'd post the *failing* code rather than just the working code that doesn't do what you want it to.

Comment: You are using the variablename 'row' twice. Maybe you should post a complete example of the code that fails so we can help you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It sounds like you're writing a bad select statement. Try the following:

```
public void Something(DataTable dt)
{
    var data = from row in dt.AsEnumerable()
               select new { 
                            Order = row["Order"].ToString(), 
                            Something = row["Something"].ToString(),
                            Customer = row["Customer"].ToString(),
                            Address = row["Address"].ToString()
                          };
}
```

That will create a new collection of Anonymously Typed objects that you can iterate over and use as needed. Keep in mind, though, that you want be able to return `data` from the function. If you need that functionality, you need to create a concrete type to use (in place of anonymous types).

Comment: Yeah I was forgetting the new keywords.  Still not used to these anonymous delegates and all that, I forgot.  Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

I think you should use select new like this query for example:

```
var q = from o in db.Orders
        where o.Products.ProductName.StartsWith("Asset") && 
              o.PaymentApproved == true
        select new { name   = o.Contacts.FirstName + " " +
                              o.Contacts.LastName, 
                     product = o.Products.ProductName, 
                     version = o.Products.Version + 
                              (o.Products.SubVersion * 0.1)
                   };
```

Answer (score 0):

You probably want the following.

```
var data = from row
           in dt.AsEnumerable()
           select new { Order = row["Order"].ToString(), Version = row["Version"].ToString() };
```